# Neo4j cypher for co-favorited plus additional attribute

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am learning Neo4j and decided to take one of the sample queries and add a twist to it.  I took this example http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/cypher-cookbook-co-favorited-places.html and wanted to say what if there was an additional attribute that you could use to filter the results by.  My test I put together was to have tags in the graph as well and then I wanted to search by overlapped favorites desc then by overlapping tags desc.

Here is the sample data I am using:

```
CREATE (Keanu:Person {name:'Keanu Reeves', born:1964})
CREATE (Carrie:Person {name:'Carrie-Anne Moss', born:1967})
CREATE (Laurence:Person {name:'Laurence Fishburne', born:1961})
CREATE (Hugo:Person {name:'Hugo Weaving', born:1960})
CREATE (UserBart:User {username:'bart' })
CREATE (UserHomer:User {username:'homer' })
CREATE (UserMarge:User {username:'marge' })
CREATE (Male:Tag {name:'male' })
CREATE (Female:Tag {name:'female' })
CREATE (BadHair:Tag {name:'badhair' })
CREATE
  (UserBart)-[:FAVORITE]->(Keanu),
  (UserBart)-[:FAVORITE]->(Laurence),
  (UserBart)-[:FAVORITE]->(Carrie),
  (UserHomer)-[:FAVORITE]->(Carrie),
  (UserHomer)-[:FAVORITE]->(Hugo),
  (UserMarge)-[:FAVORITE]->(Keanu),
  (UserMarge)-[:FAVORITE]->(Laurence),
  (UserMarge)-[:FAVORITE]->(Carrie),
  (Male)-[:TAGGED]->(Keanu),
  (Male)-[:TAGGED]->(Laurence),
  (Male)-[:TAGGED]->(Hugo),
  (Female)-[:TAGGED]->(Carrie),
  (BadHair)-[:TAGGED]->(Keanu),
  (BadHair)-[:TAGGED]->(Laurence)
```

I would like to answer this question: for all the people who favorited Keanu Reeves, who else have they favorited and if there is a tie breaker show the person with the most related tags first.  With the sample data, there are two people that were favorited by users who also favorited Keanu: Carrie and Laurence.  Carrie has no overlapping tags with Keanu while Laurence has two overlapping tags.  I would like to get the following results:

```
Name        SharedFavCount     OverlapTagCount
Laurence    2                  2
Carrie      2                  0
```

I have tried a bunch of different cyphers with different combination and haven't been able to crack it.

The cypher I find the oddest - I probably don't fully understand cyphers yet - is this one where I am explicitly saying I don't want Keanu in the results but alas he appears in the results.  Here is that cypher along with the results.

```
MATCH (anchor:Person)<-[:FAVORITE]-(u:User)-[:FAVORITE]->(similiar:Person)
OPTIONAL MATCH (anchor)<-[:TAGGED]-(t:Tag)-[:TAGGED]->(similiar2:Person)
WHERE anchor.name = 'Keanu Reeves'
AND similiar.name <> 'Keanu Reeves'
AND similiar.name = similiar2.name
return similiar.name, count(DISTINCT u.username), count(DISTINCT t.name)
```

and the results for that cypher:

```
Name             SharedFavCount      OverlapTagCount
Carrie           3                   0
Hugo             1                   0
Laurence         2                   2
Keanu            2                   0
```

Any ideas how I can get the desired results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [GraphGist](https://gist.github.com/jexp/b0d21122a6f1a5d7cbc7) answering your question interactively.

Your `WHERE` filtering for *"Keanu Reeves"* is applied to the wrong match, move it upwards behind the `MATCH` clause.
And add an `ORDER BY` for your tie-break rule.

You can also simplify your query, you don't need the additional constraints, rather reuse the +similiar+ identifier. *Keanu Reeves* cannot appear as +similiar+ as the +FAVORITE+ relationship pointing to him is already used in the path.

```
MATCH (anchor:Person)<-[:FAVORITE]-(u:User)-[:FAVORITE]->(similiar:Person)
WHERE anchor.name = 'Keanu Reeves'
OPTIONAL
MATCH (anchor)<-[:TAGGED]-(t:Tag)-[:TAGGED]->(similiar)
RETURN similiar.name, count(DISTINCT u.username) as favs, count(DISTINCT t.name) as tags
ORDER BY favs DESC, tags DESC
```